# Problem triggering download in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on a bit of code that is supposed to trigger a download from a pop-up window that was working in IE7 but broken in IE8 (also working in chrome and firefox).  The situation is that the parent window is from a different domain then the download link and open's a pop-up to a url (say, http://someother.domain.com/downloadHelper.jsp) that generates and returns this bit of javascript:

```
downloadURL=http://someother.domain.com/downloadServlet?content=blarg.txt
snip...
window.opener.top.location.href = downloadURL;
snip...
```

Using fiddler/js debugging to see what the browser's doing step-by-step - in IE7 I see this

1. Main pop-up comes up and makes request for the downloadHelper.jsp
2. window.opener line causes request to downloadServlet
3. Main window comes up with IE's download dialog.

However, in IE8 I see this:

1. Main pop-up comes up and makes request for the downloadHelper.jsp
2. window.opener line opens a new pop-up with makes a request to downloadServlet
3. Both pop-up windows close with no IE download dialog

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Add `X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7` to your page or response headers to force IE8 and 9 to use the IE7 Document Mode (only if you are 100% sure your visitors will be using IE browsers).